# Unexpected token, expected in onConfirm in react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, npm

> I'm trying to implement [react-native-modal-datetime-picker](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-modal-datetime-picker) in my
>   app

**props**

```
export default class App extends React.Component {  
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      cdate: '',
     setDate: '',
     isVisible: false,
     setVisible: false
    };
  }
```

> **Source Code**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
    import {
      View,
      ScrollView,
      DatePickerIOS,
      TouchableOpacity,
      Text,
      TextInput,
      Button,
      StyleSheet
    } from "react-native";
    import RBSheet from "react-native-raw-bottom-sheet";
    import data from "./static.json";

import DateTimePicker from 'react-native-modal-datetime-picker'; 


export default class App extends React.Component {
```

const { cdate, isVisible, setDate, setVisible } = this.state;

```
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text style={styles.textTitle}>REACT NATIVE RAW BOTTOMSHEET</Text>
        <View style={styles.buttonContainer}>

          <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.Scrollable.open()} style={styles.button}>
            <Text style={styles.buttonTitle}>SCROLLABLE</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>     
        </View>

        {/* Grid Menu */}
        <RBSheet
          ref={ref => {
            this.Scrollable = ref;
          }}
          closeOnDragDown
          customStyles={{
            container: {
              borderTopLeftRadius: 10,
              borderTopRightRadius: 10
            }
          }}
        >
          <ScrollView>
            <View style={styles.gridContainer}>
             <DateTimePicker
  mode="time"
  isVisible={isVisible}
  cdate={cdate}
  onConfirm={cdate => {
    setDate(cdate.toTimeString());
    setVisible(false);
  }}
  onCancel={() => this.setState({ setVisible: false })}
/>
            </View>

          </ScrollView>
        </RBSheet>

      </View>
    );
  }
}
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: "center",
    backgroundColor: "#F5FCFF"
  },
  textTitle: {
    fontSize: 20,
    marginTop: 120
  },
  buttonContainer: {
    alignItems: "center",
    marginTop: 50
  },
  button: {
    width: 150,
    backgroundColor: "#4EB151",
    paddingVertical: 10,
    alignItems: "center",
    borderRadius: 3,
    margin: 10
  },

});
```

> **This is the error i'm getting**

[image: error in emulator]

> **This is how it should work**
>   [image: how it should look like]

*****updated*****

> i'm getting the error " SyntaxError:\App.js: Unexpected token (21:6)
>
> 19 | export default class App extends React.Component {   20 |
>
> > 21 | const { cdate, isVisible, setDate, setVisible } = this.state;
> >          |       ^   22 |      23 |   render() {   24 |     return (   at App.js:21:6 " can you help

*AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA*

Comment: const { cdate, isVisible, setDate, setVisible } = this.state; this should be inside the class

Comment: is it working now?

Comment: @ i'm getting the error " SyntaxError:\App.js: Unexpected token (21:6)

  19 | export default class App extends React.Component {
  20 | 
> 21 | const { cdate, isVisible, setDate, setVisible } = this.state;
     |       ^
  22 |   
  23 |   render() {
  24 |     return (
  at App.js:21:6 " can you help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
const { cdate, isVisible, setDate, setVisible } = this.state;

<DateTimePicker
  mode="time"
  isVisible={isVisible}
  cdate={cdate}
  onConfirm={cdate => {
    setDate(cdate.toTimeString());
    setVisible(false);
  }}
  onCancel={() => this.setState({ setVisible: false })}
/>
```

Comment: I tried but i'm getting this error "undefined is not an object (evaluating '_this$state.cDate') "   can you help

Comment: its' `cdate` ... not `cDate` ... just a typo in your var-name

Comment: @ Hend El-Sahli   it gives the same error "undefined is not an object (evaluating '_this$state.cdate') ", this time with cdate

Comment: Post your whole class plz

Comment: @Venda Where you define you `component state object` ?

Comment: Hend El-Sahli under the class component

Comment: i'm getting the error " SyntaxError:\App.js: Unexpected token (21:6)

19 | export default class App extends React.Component { 20 |

21 | const { cdate, isVisible, setDate, setVisible } = this.state; | ^ 22 | 23 | render() { 24 | return ( at App.js:21:6 " can you help

Comment: `const { cdate, isVisible, setDate, setVisible } = this.state;` has to be inside your `render` function

Comment: @ Hend El-Sahli  then I get the error "TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating '_this$state.cdate')"